# Fileabeat - multiple files with multiline logs

Tags: elasticsearch, filebeat

I have filebeat rpm installed onto a unix server and I am attempting to read 3 files with multiline logs and I know a bit about multiline matching using filebeat but I am wondering if its possible to have matching for 3 separate logs.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you might basically need [multiple prospectors](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/multiple-prospectors.html),

Example, *(not tested)*

```
filebeat.prospectors:
- input_type: log
  paths:
    - /var/log/app1/file1.log
  multiline.pattern: '^\[[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}'
  multiline.negate: false
  multiline.match: after

- input_type: log
  paths:
    - "/var/log/app2/file2.log"

- input_type: log
  paths:
    - "/var/log/app3/file3.log"
```

- `negate: true` and `match: after` => specify that any line that **does not match the specified pattern** belongs to the **previous line**.

### References

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/multiple-prospectors.html

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/multiline-examples.html

[Understanding Multiline](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/understanding-multiline/77920/2)